# Woocommerce product download URL

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm making a skin for The Grid plugin (https://theme-one.com/docs/the-grid/#developer_guide).

All the products are virtual and downloadable — I've managed to make an add to cart function, but need to download products instantly too. Is there a meta key for the file url (combed the database and couldn't spot one) or a way to get it?

Currently I've got something that just returns an array:

```
$output .= '<p><a href="' . $tg_el->get_item_meta('_downloadable_files') . '" download target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-download"></i> Download Image</a></p>';
```

Thought I'd found a possible solution: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/199884/134263 but am not great with php and I'm unsure how to implement it.

Any pointers would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Woocommerce downloadable are arrays, as you can see on the back-end it gives you the option to add multiple downloadable.

assuming you are on a product template where the global variable `$product` can be initiated, you can get the list of downloadable from a product as mentioned by other post using the method `$product->get_files()` and this will give you an array of downloadable files and you have to loop through each array item to get the data like name and link which you have to use the `foreach` loop.

Im not sure where exactly you wanted to add this but based on you code you can do something like this,

```
// Declaring $product variable from woocommerce, this isn't needed if previously declared
global $product;

// get all downloadable files from the product
$files = $product->get_files(); 

//Loop through each downloadable file
foreach( $files as $file ) {
    //store the html with link and name in $output variable assuming the $output variable is declared above
    $output .= '<p><a href="' . $file['file'] . '" download target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-download"></i> '. $file['name'].'</a></p>';
}
```

The link should be then added to that $output variable you are using which can be `echo` or `return`

Also, try learning basic php, its not that hard, working with php without knowledge is much harder than learning its basics :)